# Can not format datetime in laravel 7.2.2

Tags: laravel

i am currently working in `laravel 7.2.2` and I am trying to format following `datetime` in to `'M d Y'` .

```
"created_at": "2020-03-23T12:17:29.000000Z",
```

Previously, in laravel 6, datetime formats are like this: `2019-12-02 20:01:00`. 
but now, date format is changed, and appearing like above: `2020-03-23T12:17:29.000000Z`.

In laravel 6 i used to format my datetime as following code:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $createdAt = Carbon::parse($post['created_at']);
        $post['created_at'] = $createdAt->format('M d Y'); 
}
```

But it gives me same output as above `2020-03-23T12:17:29.000000Z` .
So, how can i format my datetime in laravel 7.
Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a breaking change introduced in Laravel 7.0.  You can still format it the way you want.

You can override the `serializeDate` method on your model:

```
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
 protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
 {
     return $date->format('M d Y');
 }
```

See the [docs in the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization) for more information.

HTH

Comment: Hmm.  Did you try with a new model - save a new one, and then output the date?  This is for serializing, where those new ISO dates are introduced.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. do i need to create another model for this code? i pasted above code in my existing model (i.e. Post)

Comment: No, sorry.  I just meant - create a new Post model and run through your code with the override in place.  Try making a new Post model and outputting the created_at date.  Without parsing - just show `$post->created_at`  IE Skip the Parse and see what comes out - the date will format correctly from the model

Comment: so basically i should delete my existing Post model and make a new Post model and then check it?

Comment: No, not the model.  Just try this:  `$post = Post::create([xxx])`.  Then see what it shows without the parse on the `created_at` field.  `dd($post->created_at);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) to transform the data from your model to what the API should respond with. That way you won't need to touch the data and how the data is saved in your model.

It could look like something like this, given that your column names are the same:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Post extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'text' => $this->text,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('M d Y'),
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at->format('M d Y'),
        ];
    }
}
```